# how to get "gen_server" 's local name?

Tags: erlang

It is possible to save the local name in gen_server's state, but I think since it is already stored in the gen_server, it is possible to fetch it.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start gen_server with command like this:

```
{ok,Pid} = gen_server:start_link({local, localName}, Module, Args, Options]).
```

you can obtain localName by command:

```
process_info(Pid, registered_name).
```